# Using local gradle plugin in a composite build, using groovy convention scripts

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Trying to move from groovy conventions being in the buildSrc directory, into a composite build instead. In the project, is a library and a java gradle plugin. Both of which are published and build as their own modules.

Instead of using a pre-compiled  groovy script in buildSrc, I was hoping to store some groovy config in it's own module. Then use `includeBuild` to bring it in as needed.

I have the following project structure in gradle:

```
project/
├─ custom-java-plugin/
│  ├─ main/
│  │  ├─ java/
│  │  │  ├─ Plugin.java
│  ├─ build.gradle
├─ some-lib/
│  ├─ build.gradle
├─ groovy-plugin/
│  ├─ main/
│  │  ├─ groovy/
│  │  │  ├─ my.convention.gradle
│  ├─ build.gradle
├─ build.gradle
├─ settings.gradle
```

I want to apply the `custom-java-plugin` within the `my.convention.gradle` groovy plugin. I've tried the following in `my.convention.gradle`;

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'custom-java-plugin'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

When I try to apply this to `some-lib` I get the error that gradle cannot find the `custom-java-plugin`

It is setup to be included in the root `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    includeBuild('custom-java-plugin')
}

rootProject.name = 'root'

// Plugin setup
includeBuild('custom-java-plugin')
includeBuild('groovy-plugin')

include('some-lib')
```

What am I missing here? I don't see why my library can see the `groovy-plugin` via includeBuild, but the groovy plugin can't see the compiled java plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle) build itself. You can see that there is [build-logic](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/build-logic) and [build-logic-commons](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/build-logic-commons), both with their own `settings.gradle.kts`. `build-logic-commons` is included twice, once in the `./settings.gradle.kts` and once in the `./build-logic/settings.gradle.kts`. This is necessary if you want to use its plugins in both `build-logic` and the main project.

I'd suggest to follow this convention, i.e., put plugins used only for the main build in `build-logic` and plugins used by other plugins as well as the main build into `build-logic-commons`.